# Какие операции в JavaSсript являются атомарными, а какие нет?

Tags: javascript

Атомарная операция — операция, которая либо выполняется целиком, либо не выполняется вовсе; операция, которая не может быть частично выполнена и частично не выполнена.

**UPDATE**

Технология [Atomics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics) поддерживается только в FF. Выходит что все операции в JS являются не атомарными и могут прерываться в любой момент? Видимо так, из-за однопоточности эта проблема не стояла.

Comment: а что, в яваскрипте многопоточность появилась?

Comment: @Grundy давно есть, в виде воркеров

Comment: @PashaPash, там вроде с разделяемыми данными не очень, а без них  можно считать все операции атомарными :)

Comment: @Grundy ну вот как только в js появилась возможность шарить память между потоками, через SharedArrayBuffer - сразу понадобились атомарные операции

Comment: @PashaPash, только пока они, судя по всему, только в FF, и то, отключены по-умолчанию.